# PHP Folders Location

Tags: php

hi im in a folder /login/ & I want to use header to goto /apps/news/ so how do I type the location ?

Comment: Please add more detail. Do you mean a header redirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
header("Location: http://yourdomain/apps/news/");
```

Edit: Removing relative URL example after Pekka's comment, which is correct. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30 for the details.

Comment: According to the specs, `location` always needs a full URL.

Comment: write `exit()` after `header()`

Comment: this goes to /login/apps/news/, thats not what I want.

Comment: It worked, and from experience works across IE, FF and Chrome, but it is not technically correct, fwiw.

Answer (score 2):

```
header("Location: http://your-url/apps/news/")
```